# "Add as Link" for visual studio 2010 AddIn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, add-in

I can't figure out how to add a "linked" file to a project "Add as link" programmatically in an AddIn for Visual Studio 2010 - the way you do it via the solution explorer "Add->Existing Item->Add as Link" in visual studio.

Would appreciate some pointers on this.

Thank you!

/Bilsaboob

Answer (score 0):

The Add Existing Item dialog's add button has a down arrow on the right, it subtle. But it will change the Add to "Add as Link"